# Outlook Public Folders Performance and Maximum Capacity

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, outlook, contacts

I'd like to store contacts in a Public Folder using Outlook/Exchange Server 2003. Does anyone know if there is a practical limit to the number of contacts I can add to such a folder?

How do public folders perform when 1000, 5000, or 10000 contacts are added (e.g. is Outlook performance affected, or are searches against the contact list unresponsive)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public folders behave similarly to any other exchange mailbox.  Performance is severely impacted with large number of items in a folder.

I think you are better off using LDAP.